# Replace class with its stub for test

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-3.6

I have following example code:

```
class AuxiliaryClass:
    @staticmethod
    def high_cost_method():
        "Do something"

class MyTestedClass:
    def do_something(self):
        something = AuxiliaryClass.high_cost_method()
        "do something else"
```

I want to test `MyTestedClass`. For this purpose I've created `AuxiliaryClassStub` class to override `high_cost_method()`. I want my test to execute `do_something()` from `MyTestedClass`, but `do_something()` should use stub instead of real class.
How can I do that?
My real auxiliary class is quite big, it has a lot of methods and I will use it in many tests, so I don't want to patch single methods. I need to replace whole class during tests.

Note, that `high_cost_method()` is static, so mocking `__init__()` or `__new__()` will not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use `self.__class__.high_cost_method` inside `do_something`? This way you avoid the direct reference to the class name, which should enable subclassing and overriding the staticmethod with the one from AuxiliaryClass.

```
class MyTestedClass:
    def do_something(self):
        something = self.__class__.high_cost_method()
        something()

    @staticmethod
    def high_cost_method():
        print("high cost MyTestedClass")


class AuxiliaryClass(MyTestedClass):
    @staticmethod
    def high_cost_method():
        print("high cost AuxiliaryClass")
```

Then you get

```
test = AuxiliaryClass()
test.high_cost_method()
```

> high cost AuxiliaryClass

and otherwise

```
test = MyTestedClass()
test.high_cost_method()
```

> high cost MyTestedClass

Comment: I don't think it is good solution. I will need to modify my classes for it. I want to do as less as possible changes for my code, and do all mocking in tests.